# Why isn't my margin:10px auto; working?

Tags: html, css

For some reason my parent div ( `#box_one` ) is being centered in my page perfectly fine by using ( `#box_one{ margin: 10px auto 10px auto; }` ), but when I try the same technique for it's child element ( `#box_one > div` ) it only centers it vertically. Can someone explain why this is happening?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>  
    <title>Text</title> 
    <style type="text/css">    
        #box_one{
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 400px;
            margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
        }

        #box_one > div{
            height: 200px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body> 
    <div id="box_one">
        <div></div>
    </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: It's working fine if you add a width to your second `div`

Comment: While your question has been answered, I just figured I'd chime-in with a useful shorthand for your CSS. If your vertical margins are identical, and your horizontal margins are identical, you can actually do `margin: 10px auto;` as a shortcut. It's essentially `margin: *(vertical margins)* *(horizontal margins)*` - Nothing wrong with your method at all, just a heads-up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add a explicit `width` to child `div`

```css
#box_one {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
#box_one > div {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 50%
}
```

```html
<div id="box_one">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

`

Comment: Thank you for the visual representation, this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the child element *is* being centered, in the sense that its auto horizontal margins are both being zeroed out. The *reason* for this, is because your child element, unlike `#box_one` itself, doesn't have a set width.

When the width of a block box (`display: block`) is not explicitly set, or set to auto, the box will stretch horizontally to fit its containing block, [resulting in its auto horizontal margins being zeroed out](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#blockwidth):

> If 'width' is set to 'auto', any other 'auto' values become '0' and 'width' follows from the resulting equality.

Comment: You, my sir, have been very helpful. Very simply put!

Answer (score 0):

Just add a width to `#box_one > div{}` and you will be golden.